# Scale factor of a function plotter

Tags: java, algorithm, math, plot

I have done my own function plotter with java which works quite well.
All you have to do is to iterate over the with (pixels) of the panel and calculate the y-value. Then plot it with a poly-line onto the screen and that's it.

But here comes my problem: There is a scale factor between the number of pixels and the value which I want to plot.
For example I'm at the 304' iteration (iterating over the with value of the plot panel). Now I calculate the corresponding value for this pixel position (304) by the rule of three. This gives me 1.45436. Then I calculate the sin based on this value. Which is transcendetal number. Then I use again the rule of tree to determine which y-pixel this value corresponds to. Doing so, I have to round because the pixel is an integer. And there is my data loss. This data loss may give me the following result:

[image]

This looks not really nice. If I play around with resizing the window I sometimes get a smooth result.

How can I fix this problem? I've actually never seen such plots in any other function plotter.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with your code. Perhaps you're doing part of the math with integers that should be floating point. If you don't post code, you'll never get an answer.

Comment: Are you overthinking this? You are not really working based on pixels. When I zoom your plot, I see that the red line is anti-aliased, which makes sense, because you haven't drawn pixels but a poly line. But that anti-aliasing leads me to the assumption that the coordinates for the points can be floating-point numbers. What happens if you don't round?

Comment: The rounding was the mistake. Passing now floating values to the polyline works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this in Java, you might consider composing your data points to a [`Path2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/geom/Path2D.html). That would have floating point coordinates, and the drawing engine would take care of smoothing things down. You might have to [disable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint%28java.awt.RenderingHints.Key,%20java.lang.Object%29) [stroke control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_STROKE_CONTROL), though.

Comment: Thank you. I was already using Path2D, but I did not consider that I can pass floating point values to its methods. Doing this it works well now.